# Can't create database even with all privileges

Tags: mysql, mariadb, permissions

[mariaDB on RedHat 7.7]

I just want to create a new database, but found "access denied":

```
create database lamp_k;
```

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'lamp'@'localhost' to database 'lamp_k'

These are my privileges:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for lamp@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'lamp'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F90C7030DCB590F7C8E0ED955DA6222DE699A9E8' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `lamp_*`.* TO 'lamp'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple.

- You have grants to do things in any existing database that starts with `lamp_`.
- You do not have permission to create a new database even if it starts with `lamp_`.
- You would need at least `GRANT CREATE ON *.*` to create databases.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Before the changes actually take action, you need to run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

EDIT:
Just saw that you tried to grant Privileges on a database which doesn't exists. You need to give them global privileges to create databases.

Comment: Permissions were assigned by the administrator days ago, no need to flush

Comment: @anthony Does you want to say that server reboots during this days? If no - flush, it is safe.

Comment: i did it. it doesn't work.